# jquery - checking if element is clicking and sub-elements aren't clicked

Tags: jquery, click, element

I have this html code:

```
<div id="area">Click me <span id="forbidden">Hi Guys</span></div>
```

I would like to do check if only #area clicked, but not the area of forbidden, eventhough it is inside the div "area".

Thanks in advance,
Daniel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`.target` property](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/) of the `event` object will give you the DOM element that initiated the event:

```
$("#area").click(function(e) {
   if (e.target.id != "forbidden") {
       // do something
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to use the `stopPropagation` on the forbidden element.

```
$('#area').click(function(){
  // not forbidden
});


$('#forbidden').click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```